# Select with inner join, start and Limit SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select and rows from the images table with inner join and start with limit `SQL`? I have tried the following. I want to select limited images from the image table.

```
SELECT *
FROM images
JOIN users ON images.users_user_id = users.user_id
LIMIT 3,5
ORDER BY image_created DESC
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it to work.

```
SELECT images.image_id, images.image_url, users.user_name 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 0, 6) images 
    INNER JOIN users 
    ON images.users_user_id = users.user_id 
ORDER BY image_created DESC
```

Comment: I don't think there is any reason for a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize `START`.  `OFFSET` is the keyword that should be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM images i INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON i.users_user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY i.image_created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3;
```

Notice that I also added table aliases to the query.  I would (as a general rule) advise you not to use `select *` across tables but rather to select the columns you really need.

Comment: Can `OFFSET/LIMIT` be used before `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: I'm getting syntax error with this example.

Comment: As per [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) the correct syntax is `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3`. If you want to start from 3rd row you need to use `OFFSET 2` (skip first 2 rows).

Comment: @Prdp . . . No.  Thank you.